# URLClassLoader issue for jars created with JarOutputStream

Tags: java, jar, classloader, urlclassloader

the URLClassLoader class fails to load classes from the jar created programatically using the code listed below, whereas when i create a jar with the same classes using **jar cf %jarname% %sources%** it works fine. Is there a difference between the jars created using **jar cf** and **JarOutputStream**.

```
public static ByteArrayInputStream createJar(File file) throws IOException {
    Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
    manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JarOutputStream target = new JarOutputStream(bytes, manifest);
    for (File child : file.listFiles()) {
        addJarEntries(child, target, "");
    }
    target.flush();
    target.close();
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes.toByteArray());
}

private static void addJarEntries(File source, JarOutputStream target, String path) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    try
    {
        if (source.isDirectory())
        {
            String name = path +source.getName() + File.separator;
            for (File nestedFile: source.listFiles())
                addJarEntries(nestedFile, target, name);
            return;
        }

        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(path + source.getName());
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);
        while (true)
        {
            int count = in.read(buffer);
            if (count == -1)
                break;
            target.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        target.closeEntry();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}
```

Best Regards,
Keshav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jar` command uses `JarOutputStream` to create a JAR file ([source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/tools/jar/Main.java)) so it cannot be the fault of that class *per se*.  However, it is possible that you missed some important step in the JAR creation process.  For instance, you may have included a malformed manifest.

You should be able to compare your code with the source code of the `jar` command to see if you have missed something important.

Comment: thanks the link helped, i was not adding entries for folder. after adding the folder entries i am able to load classes